# Why does this header after an echo not generate an error?

Tags: php, header, character-encoding

Why does this not throw an error:

```
echo "texto em cirílico sem conversão";
echo "русская слова";
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Never mind the actual text, but I did `echo` some text, then sent a new header, which is obviously another header?

What am I missing here?

PS. I'm basing my thoughts on the general error which pops up when you try to send a `header(location....` type of thing, but you had some errors before, and the compiler screamed about headers having already been sent.

Comment: The order of your description and your code are not in sync

Comment: Are you using output_buffering ?

Comment: Then it must be something with your error_reporting. You must have warning disabled.

Comment: Do you get the error if you change the content-type? If you're not modifying any already sent headers PHP might exclude it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you have output buffering enabled? Check your php.ini for `output_buffering`. If this is switched on, all printed text will first be cached in the output buffer before being sent to STDOUT.

Comment: `output_buffering = 4096` - Default settings from XAMPP it seems

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `flush();` after the `echo`s and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: It does actually. If I add a `flush();` after the `echo`it does send out an error. What does this mean?

Comment: @Felipe: it means that PHP was internally buffering your output instead of sending it out immediately. So now you know why it didn't complain. :)

Comment: I wish I could flag 2 answers as the right one but tobyS was first

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `header` display a warning (which may be disabled) instead of error if headers already sent ? I'd add `if (headers_sent()) {die('headers_sent);'}` before calling `header` for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending output before you have called header. The solution to this is either fix output_buffering values or implement the use of ob_start(); and ob_end_flush();.

I hope this helps! :)